# Magento 2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsSHA is not defined

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I am getting this error message when I try to use `JQuery 1.11.3: Uncaught ReferenceError: jsSHA` is not defined.

I actually try to download the `JQuery` js file to call it locally but I gets the same message.

Comment: Should jQuery 1.11.3 include jsSHA?

Comment: how you have caled jquery in your file?